# Failed to click on URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver.exe");

```
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    webDriver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com"); // Open google.com

    webDriver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("NCR");
    webDriver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
  webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[6]/div[4]/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a/span")).click();
```

Success: Open chrome , go to google.com , serch for ncr and click on search
Failed to click on the first option of the results (in my case: www.ncr.com)
Please help me to click on the result by few options: css, xpath or text

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I idea is to write a dynamic xpath. I hope the xpath in the question was a browser generated one.

Try with this

```
//Clicks the first result
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div//h3[1]/a")).click();
```

To know more about dynamic xpath refer this=>[Dynamic XPATH](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/)